# Combine text files preserving separator and formatting

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Is possible to have a sed or cat command to merge two text files? for example:

**File 1:**

`1;3;F;100`

**File 2:**

`2;'john'`

How to get an output like this?

`1;3;F;100;2;'john'`

Because when I do `cat file1 file2 > file-merged` does created in the wrong format for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paste` command will do this. For example:

```
$ paste -d ';' file1.txt file2.txt
1;3;F;100;2;'john'
```

'paste' merges the corresponding lines in both files. The '-d' sets the delimiter added between the lines.

Comment: I guess I need to run this in a loop or it will work with my two 100k files?

Comment: It concatenates all the lines in both files. That is, line 1 in both files, line 2 in both files, etc.

Comment: That is awesome! I didnt know that command existed! :D thanks mate